# Make Bootstrap btn-group display right to left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The buttons displayed in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3ebee150/) fiddle are not properly displayed: Since the text is in Hebrew, the first button (with `id="first"`) should be the most right one, but is currently the most left one.

Playing with the style, it seems that this is caused by the `display` attribute of `btn-group` class (whose value is `inline-block`), and when I change it to `display: flex` the buttons are displayed in the correct order, but the first and last child's borders (right and left borders) get flipped.

I was trying some advice found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891405/bootstrap-rtl-right-to-left-input-groups) question, but didn't manage to make it work.

Code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div dir="rtl">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="first" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"></span>&nbsp;אחת
    </button>
    <button id="second" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>&nbsp;שתיים
    </button>
    <button id="third" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>&nbsp;שלוש
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it some more trials, and eventually got it with the trick of rotating the `btn-group` and then rotating back the text (keeping each cell's content in its own span element):

```css
.rotate
{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.rotate-back
{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: inline-block;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group pull-right rotate" role="group">
  <button id="first" type="button" class="btn btn-default ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"></span><span class="rotate-back">&nbsp;אחת</span>
  </button>
  <button id="second" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span><span class="rotate-back">&nbsp;שתיים</span>
  </button>
  <button id="third" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span><span class="rotate-back">&nbsp;שלוש</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap floats your elements, you need also to overwrite `float` direction:

```css
div[dir="rtl"] .btn-group .btn
{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div dir="rtl">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="first" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"></span>&nbsp;אחת
    </button>
    <button id="second" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>&nbsp;שתיים
    </button>
    <button id="third" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>&nbsp;שלוש
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

you can also use the class [`.pull-right`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats).

> **HeyJude  wrote:**  the borders get flipped. If you look closely, you'll notice that the left border (the one with the rounded corners) of the first child should be the right one, and vice versa for the last child.

for the rounded corners, a trick could be to use transform instead rewritting CSS. It requires to encapsulate text within the span too. Icone is generated via a pseudo and should not mess it up.

```css
div[dir="rtl"] .btn:first-of-type,
div[dir="rtl"] .btn:last-of-type,
div[dir="rtl"] .btn:first-of-type span,
div[dir="rtl"] .btn:last-of-type span {
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div dir="rtl">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="first" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd">&nbsp;אחת</span>
    </button>
    <button id="second" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">&nbsp;שתיים</span>
    </button>
    <button id="third" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign">&nbsp;שלוש</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said - here too the borders get flipped. If you look closely, you'll notice that the left border (the one with the rounded corners) of the first child should be the right one, and vice versa for the last child.

Comment: @HeyJude i just added a second snippet , using bootstrap class for the float and a transform trick for the rounded pieces.

Comment: Thank you. I gave it some more trials, since your update does solves the flipped borders problem, but changes the text font (and the spacing between the glyphicon and the text, which might be the result of the font). You put me on the right track, and would like your opinion on my own solution.

Comment: @HeyJude scale(-1,1), rotateY(180deg) are similar.I applied that mirror effect on the button and its child, you did on the main row then the button child. Yours might be less flexible, if inside a single row you have rtl & ltr content. I would keep the dir attribute and use the selector [dir=rtl] as a generic rule to avoid extra classes. missing one class or not knowing they exist or their purpose while updating content, can be a waste of time. However, the best method is the one you understand & feel confortable with. The 3 snippets of us gives you many ways to finalyse your own method. ;)

Comment: @HeyJude keeping the dir attributes is also giving meanings to the content somehow. One thing i do when i get confuse about the structure and css to apply, i reload the document without any CSS to check if the content still makes sense :) html  first, in my own & humble opinion